# Error in .rect_dendrogram(dend, k = k, palette = rect_border, rect_fill = rect_fill, : k must be between 2 and 97

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, topic-modeling, dendrogram, dendextend

I am trying to estimate a cluster dendrogram in R for a structural topic model I produced with 98 topics.

I first ran the following which worked well:

```
res.hc <- eclust(scale(out_corr$cor), "hclust", nboot = 500)
```

I then attempting to visualize the dendrogram using the following syntax:

```
fviz_dend(res.hc, rect = TRUE)
```

Here, I received the following error:
Error in .rect_dendrogram(dend, k = k, palette = rect_border, rect_fill = rect_fill, :
k must be between 2 and 97

Is this because the number of topics in my model is 98? If so, is there a way to still visualize the dendrogram without reducing my topics to 97?

Thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: I tried running the same cluster analysis with 97 topics and now I am getting an error that says K must be between 2 and 96 [Error in .rect_dendrogram(dend, k = k, palette = rect_border, rect_fill = rect_fill, : 
k must be between 2 and 96]. Does anyone know the maximum number of topics that can be clustered and/or how to get around this?

Comment: Could you please try to recreate this with dendextend::rect.dendrogram and see which errors you are getting? If you can create a self contained example of the error that would be super helpful in helping to debug this.

Comment: I will give it a try and see whether it clarifies things. Thank you!

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much! I will post the solution shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps helped to resolve the issue:

1. estimate cluster dendrogram

```
res.hc <- eclust(scale(out_corr$cor), "hclust", nboot = 500)
```

2. install dendextend

```
install.packages("dendextend")
library(dendextend)
```

3. install dplyr

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
```

4. save cluster estimate as a dendrogram

```
dend<-as.dendrogram(res.hc)
```

5. color in cluster levels

```
par(mar=c(1,1,1,7))
dend %>%
  set("labels_col", value = c("skyblue", "red", "grey", "blue"), k=4) %>%
  set("branches_k_color", value = c("skyblue", "red", "grey", "blue"), k = 4) %>%
  plot(horiz=FALSE, axes=FALSE)
abline(v = 350, lty = 2)
```